# Arrays starting with the same character

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

How can I check the count of arrays starting with the same character? For example, I have 3 arrays starting with 0, 2 arrays with 1 and 3 arrays starting with 2.
The best way with few for loop

[image]

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: I am finding the first element but can't find the count.

Comment: arr.filter(item => item[0])

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.reduce()` method to create a resultant object having first element as key and its value as count like this:

```js
let data = [
  [0, 0],
  [0, 1],
  [0, 2],
  [1, 1],
  [1, 2],
  [2, 0],
  [2, 1],
  [2, 2],
];

let result = Object.entries(
  data.reduce((a, [f]) => (a[f] = (a[f] || 0) + 1, a), {})
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: And how can I return element which count is 1? I tried this way
var result = data.reduce((acc, [item]) => {
 var i = (acc[item] || 0) + 1;
 if(i < 2) {
  console.log('small', acc[item])
 }
//  console.log('iiiii', i)
 return (acc[item] = i, acc)
}, {})

console.log(result);